# Encriptar imagens e vídeos através do node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com o nw.js e preciso proteger imagens e vídeos que serão distribuídos com o mesmo, existe alguma forma para fazer isso com o node.js?

Comment: Defina 'proteger'.

Comment: preciso impedir que esse conteúdo seja visualizado fora do meu App

Comment: Então seu requisito é restrição de acesso, e não criptografia, correto?

Comment: sim, resolveria meu problema